# getnumberinstance cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, decimal

I have a program where I try to change the number of decimals on my double. I have a book that tells me to do import java.text.* and then this:

```
NumberFormat nf = new NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
```

but on the first line i get the error "NumberFormat.getNumberInstance() cannot be resolved to a type". why cant I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here: `NumberFormat nf = new NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();`. You need to remove the `new` keyword from there to get this: `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();`. You are accessing a `static` method, you do not need the `new` here.